# TexShop 3.57 preview pdf problem (Mac OsX El Capitan)

Tags: mactex, texshop

I have been using TexShop without any problems for a few years now.
Recently I updated to MacOS X El Capitan and LateX stopped working; I reinstalled MacTex and followed the instructions available online to fix the issues with this version of OSX and it seemed that everything was working again (in a sense it does).

However, when I use TexShop, I often encounter the following problems:

1. After sometime of normal usage, when I compile my document to generate my PDF, the preview of TexShop shows blank pages, although the PDF generated is fine when I open it with an external app. Compiling again or trying different documents does not work and I have to restart the application.
2. Once in a while it crashes and I have to force quit and restart TexShop; seems that this tends to happen when I scroll down in the preview of my document.

I do have the latest version of TexShop.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about a problem that apparently vanished with a software update

Answer (score 0):

It seems that these problems have been fixed by the latest update of TexShop, so the question is no longer relevant.

Comment: I am having similar problems, although I have updated to TeXShop 3.58 (and done a fresh re-install to be sure). Trying to read your original posting, were you saying that after upgrading to El Cap, everything stopped working; you then reinstalled MacTeX, after which you had the intermittent problems described here?