# TeXShop crash MacOS

Tags: texshop

Dear tex dot stack world,

I'm a long-time TeX and TeXShop user. Approximately 1 month ago, I installed El Capitan, and afterwards noticed a TeXShop problem that I do not see discussed on the various fora.

The issue is that when I'm using the viewer, especially when I'm scrolling between pages, the viewer freezes. When I go back to the source window, that is frozen too. The problem is solved by Force Quit, but obviously this is not a great solution. I waited for a while in the hope that this problem would be solved by an update, but that has not happened. For what it's worth, I'm using a Macbook Air. I did already try re-installing TeXShop.

My questions:

> - What is the right forum to ask this kind of question?
>
>   Does anyone have any idea what the problem is, or even roughly where it might lie?

Thanks for any advice.

PS: What I see is very similar to what is described in [this question on this site](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/276853/texshop-3-57-preview-pdf-problem-mac-osx-el-capitan) (although there was no solution given there either).

PPS: I saw a description of part of this problem in the "What's New" section of the TeXShop package. If the previewer screen goes blank, the author recommends doing Cmd + (zoom in) followed by Cmd -. I have not been able to test it as the problem has not recurred since I saw the hint.

Comment: Maybe the SuperUser forum?

Comment: I think the Apple SE site would be better, maybe...?

Comment: Does this problem still present itself?

Comment: Thanks for asking. I haven't seen the problem again, so had forgotten about it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the problem vanished, probably has retreated into its Jeannie bottle