# Can no longer typeset using mactex and pdftex is running at 98% of CPU

Tags: pdftex, mactex

Ive been using texshop on my mac for a while with no problem at all, i fixed the El Capitan problem by relocating the compiler, but for no apparent reason, by file has stopped typesetting. There is no error showing in the console. When I try and open the pdf file it says its not recognised by preview. Also when I try to compile the file, my mac runs hot and activity monitor says pdftex is running at around 98%. Ive tried uninstalling and reinstalling and i cant seem to figure out how to fix it, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Does this happen with every document, or just with one particular document?

Comment: it happens with every document

Comment: What happens if you try to compile a simple document from the command line?

Comment: Im quite new to this, so I'm not entirely sure how to do that

Comment: Make a simple document, then if you are on a mac just open terminal, load the directory of the document, and say `pdflatex <document_name>.tex`, if you have Windows do the same from the Command Prompt.

Comment: Ive just done that, and it typeset the document!

Comment: OK, now we know that TeXShop is the  problem, not TeX itself. I can't help any more because I hate IDEs and avoid using them!

Comment: Try reporting the problem to TeXShop programmers and seeing what they reply. I myself have never had this problem, and am with Lion, not El Capitan. Well, OK, TeXShop often takes ages to start compiling, but then it typesets fine. And command line also blocks in those moments.

Comment: What version do you have?

Comment: i have version 3.51

Comment: I have 3.61. Consider updating.

Comment: Thank you all so much, I've just updated it, and its now working fine!

Comment: If your problem is solved, consider accepting my answer by clicking the chackmark at its side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently version 3.51 of TeXShop has some problems in El Capitan, but updating fixes everything.

It is always a good idea to update before asking for help with a problem. Especially considered as [another question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/276853/texshop-3-57-preview-pdf-problem-mac-osx-el-capitan?rq=1) here was closed as off-topic because the issue was fixed by an update. Not sure this is a duplicate of that one, but surely the same argument for the closure of that one applies here.

To know more about this, e.g. where this problem comes from, one can ask the programmers behind TeXShop, or try their luck wading through the source which can be obtained [here](http://pages.uoregon.edu/koch/texshop/obtaining.html), and seeing if they can find the problem's source out by themselves.

> A good way to ask questions of this sort is to post a message on the MacTeX mailing list tug.org/mailman/listinfo/mactex. Dick Koch, the developer of TeXShop is active on that list.

Comment: A good way to ask questions of this sort is to post a message on the MacTeX mailing list http://tug.org/mailman/listinfo/mactex. Dick Koch, the developer of TeXShop is active on that list.